# Issue with Database Connection Switching from mydatabase to 'test' When Deploying Spring Application on Server

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, web

I have a Spring application deployed locally that connects to a database named practice, and everything runs smoothly.
However, when I upload the project to the server and run it there, it connects to a database named test.
I expect it to connect to the practice database, but I'm unsure why it switches to the test database.
I'm sure when I run in my computer it's right,nothing wrong happened and my database is MongoDB

I expect to run correctly in server with database pratice not database test

this is my config file:

`logging.level.root=info server.port=8082 spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:27017/practice`

Comment: Can you please share your application properties file. Most likely it has a profile configured that switches based on the environment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.